# Resize List Table of Gantt view SharePoint 2010

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to remove the chart area of a gantt view in SharePoint 2010 and leave only the list table visible and showing full screen. I found the following CSS code which i put in a content editor and it removes the chart and resizes the pane the table is in but the table itself still stays the same size.

```
<style>
DIV[id$='JSGrid_rightpane'] {
    DISPLAY: none
}
DIV[id$='JSGrid_leftpane'] {
    MIN-WIDTH: 100%
}</style>
```

I don't have any experience with CSS so if anynoe can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Thanks